# Using wordpress woo commerce with backbone.js/node.js framework

Tags: wordpress, node.js, backbone.js, woocommerce

I have outsourced the development of an web application that utilizes backbone.js and node.js to complete the task. Now I need to add user login and shopping cart functionality. I was considering using wordpress woo commerce for that because it's easy of use. Is that doable.

If not any recommendation for node.js simple ecommerce solution just for managing user orders and shopping cart functionality

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy using WooCommerce and they have some documentation to modify it yourself with plugins.

Wordpress in itself is a great tool for more than just blogging with all of the customization powers it provides.

I recommend using Wordpress and WooCommerce